# Click event not worked in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I am using a jquery click function:

> **Button code**

```
<input type="button" id="myButtton">
```

> **Jquery code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#myButtton").click(function () {
        alert("Mybutton");
    });
});
```

This code works in Internet Explorer but does not work in Firefox.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this could use some different catagories. i.e: Jquery

Comment: @Rich B, why did you edited the question? Are you sure that is his/her markup/code?

Comment: The jQuery code is correct and should work (at least as edited).  You might want to look to make sure that you do not have another element with an id of "myButton".

Comment: @jonstjohn, the problem is that the code is not posted by the original poster (view edit history). We have no idea how the code actually looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myButtton").click(function(){
        alert("Mybutton");
    });
```

I believe it's missing another closing brace:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#myButtton").click(function(){
        alert("Mybutton");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that element has an **id attribute**? Or does it have only a name attribute with a value of "myButton". In order to work cross browser the id attribute is mandatory, whereas name is optional (only IE and Opera AFAIK).

**N.B.**: My answer may seem idiot, but it was not the original poster that added the code example in the question (view edit history).

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you have other `input` with the same ID? Try using classes instead, or use jQuery's CSS selector like `$('input[type=button]')` instead.

I'd also recommend installing FireBug plugin for FireFox if you haven't done so already (http://www.getfirebug.com/). It'll help you debug JavaScript issues like this, and a whole lot more.